# How does a DNS lookup site get my location perfect?

Tags: networking, dns

I was just visiting DNSleaktest.com and I found that it could find my location to my town. Most IP tracers think I'm about 30 miles away, saying I'm in Luton. So is it possible that it's just really accurate or does it use another method to get your location?

Comment: Interesting, [dnsleaktest.com](http://www.dnsleaktest.com) shows more accurate location information for me than other location reporters (such as [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com)) as well.

Comment: There's geolocation enabled in your PC or Browser setup. By the way, why you don't give us more accurate informations about the system you're using. That's the best way to have an answer. :-S

Comment: yes there are tons of sites like http://www.ip2location.com/ that can give an accurate location upto 1km radius circle. I would love to know how do they do it. And @climenole, this is not limited to a  system or kind of browser that we may use. I have tried it on two different pcs with ubuntu windows having browser as chrome, mozilla and microsoft explorer. And after doing this, I found the dame exact result on IP2Location. I was using same Public IP for both systems. They were used alternately.

Comment: That is just scary.  And here I was worried about the NSA.  Better add another layer of tinfoil to my hat.  :-)

Comment: Windows 7, latest Google Chrome :s

Whale then, I guessed there must be some sort of geolocation enabled in browsers. Anyone know a way to implement it on a website? It'd be *useful* to log where my visitors come from

Comment: @climenole I happen to know that the browser I used does *not* have geolocation enabled (*and* my PC doesn't have GPS or anything like it)... now what?

Comment: They're not always accurate, with my home adsl they show my position off by almost 60 km

Comment: Wow, that's pretty crazy. So dnsleaktest is giving you guys pretty accurate readings too? When I connect with my VPN, it just from United Kingdom

Comment: You *should* be able to work out where someone is, roughly from rdns and dns. This is only useful for testing if your *vpn* is giving away your current location.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get a good estimate of location, even without GPS.

If you have WiFi (e.g. a laptop, [Wi-Fi Positioning System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system) can be used to give fairly accurate location.

If you have other radios, e.g. GSM, triangulation can be used on cell towers.

These are on top of traditional IP to location mapping which others discussed, which gives your location typically up to the city or area - sometimes down to a zip code.

Finally, note that if someone wants to be super savy, they can match you against similar IPs they have seen before (who have provided location), and although you do not have location service/sharing on, they can find your location fairly accurately.

Also, see https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1725632?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Well, he has only one JS https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ana/piwik.js

And you can look onn github https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/js/piwik.js source code. And see why is it better than others (or not).
It is under GPL v3 [licence](http://piwik.org/free-software/bsd/) so you can use it your projects.